# How can i upload an image to a node js server without a form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I have an express server running and I want to upload an image (`<input type="file">`) without the html `<form>` tag. Is this even possible?

I use this function to get the file from the input when its value has changed:

```
function readImage (input) {
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var myImg = new Image();
    myImg.onload = function () {
      var img = {
        image: myImg.src,
        file: input.files[0],
        w: this.width,
        h: this.height
      };
      return img;
    };
    myImg.src = _URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('image', input.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: '/foo',
  data: data,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    alert('Image uploaded!');
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    alert('Error uploading: ' + errorMessage);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add the server side part? I can't get it working... :(

Comment: Solved my problem! I appended not only the file but an object like { key: "lorem", img: input.files[0] }, and The files didn't show up in the req.files. Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Client Side:

```
    var image = $("#imageid")[0].files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', image);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploads/',
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        'success':function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Server Side:
 Use multer

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var path   = require("path");
    var multer = require("multer");


    var uploading = multer({

        dest: './public/uploads/'

    });


    router.post('/', uploading.single('image'),function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.file);
        res.send(req.file);
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Output:
 Server Side:

```
{ fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'Untitled.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: 'bde1b15ba5b62b4106f86b49c73720ea',
  path: './public/uploads/bde1b15ba5b62b4106f86b49c73720ea',
  size: 52375 }
```

Hope this helps!